# Jenkins level ant plugin will use system or custom java home

Tags: java, jenkins, ant

Here i am setting JAVA_HOME jenkins job level

```
***********JAVA1.7****************

export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_16

export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH

echo "** Building with $JAVA_HOME"
```

System level Java is 1.8

When i start building ant with jenkins plugin it takes Java 1.8 to build.
Jenkins output:

Why it's not pointing to Java 1.6,

But i have requirement to build same Java build(ant) with different
 version like Java1.6 and Java1.7

How can i trigger ant build with different java version in single job.

```
***********JAVA1.7****************
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_65

export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH

echo "** Building with $JAVA_HOME"
```

Here is the output of job, required to perform for Java1.6 but it's taking system level Java1.7 and ant is proceeding

```
[build] $ /home/rel/apache-ant-1.6.1/bin.
/ant -file build.xml -DBuild_branch_or_tag=master -Dmodule_name=module -Dmodule_version=6.0 -DBuild_tag=master -DDB_version=11g make
Buildfile: build.xml

SetDate:

clean:
     [echo] Removing all build files .....
   [delete] Deleting directory /home/rel/jenkins/workspace/master-module-name/module/ModuleBuild/build/com
   [delete] Deleting directory /home/rel/jenkins/workspace/master-name/module/ModuleBuild/build/module

PrintEnvironment:
     [echo] Java Home = /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.171-2.6.13.2.el7.x86_64/jre
     [echo] Java Version = 1.7
```

Can you help on this with ant plugin to build Java 1.6 and 1.7

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the java home is getting over ridden with the default value during the build

One way would be to add the java version  in the global tool configuration post which at each job level you should get a drop down option to select the java version. select 1.7 and try to build the app.

In case the above doesn't works you can use the environment inject plugin to explicitly see the java home

Also can you share few snaps of the job configuration.